# onActivityResult inside a RecyclerView.Adapter not being used

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a button inside an Adapter which goes into gallery:

```
    MyAdapter extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    onClic..{
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(
                                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                                    SELECT_FILE);}
    ....
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        }
    }
..
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to update an ImageView with the image selected from the gallery, but in order to do that I have to use onActivityResult and the compiler is complaining `method onActivityResult is never used` and `cannot resolve method onActivityResult`.

How can I go about this ?

Comment: have you tried to remove super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: yes, but it still says that the method is not being used

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note on this line you are using an `Activity` to call `startActivityForResult`:

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult();
```

`onActivityResult(...)` is a callback method and should be in the same `Activity` you used to call `startActivityForResult()`.

You are getting the compiler error because there is no such method to override named `onActivityResult(...)` for `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

EDIT:

Since you asked how you can do this properly here is one option.

Add the following interface to `MyAdapter`:

```
public interface OnClickImageListener{
    void onClick();
}
```

Then have your dialog implement that interface. In the `onClick` method do:

```
@Override
public void onClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
}
```

You can add the `onActivityResult(...)` method to your `Fragment` and it will now be called.

To use this when you create `MyAdapter` pass the `Fragment` in as an argument to the constructor and reference it as a `OnClickImageListener` so your click listener in the adapter simply becomes:

```
imageClickListener.onClick();
```

Also note you can add an index to the `onClick()` method or whatever else you need to know which item in the adapter to populate the image with once it is returned.

Comment: I used `((Activity) context)` because it was complaining otherwise. I know why I'm getting the errors, but what can I do about this ? I have only one activity for the entire project and the rest are fragments. How can I achieve what I've explained in the question ?

Comment: Is your `RecyclerView` an inner class to the `Fragment` that is using it? If it is then just call `startActivityForResult(...)` directly without using the context and override `onActivityResult(...)` in your `Fragment`.

Comment: My RecyclerView is being inflated inside a DialogFragment

Comment: What about `MyAdapter`? Is it in the same .java file as the `DialogFragment`?

Comment: I can't call it without the context because it's complaining saying that it doesn't recognize the method. No, it has it's own file.

Comment: Ok that answers the inner class question then and is why it can't access the method. You will either have to use the activity to forward the selected image to the `Fragment` or pass in the fragment hosting the `RecyclerView` to the adapter so `onActivityResult(...)` will be called on the fragment.

Comment: Thank you. You explained everything perfectly and provided a complete solution.