# Imitate 'onActivityResult' inside an Adapter of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which items' contain a button that launches an activity using startActivityForResult. The onClick method was implemented inside the adapter, and onActivityResult from the fragment that contains the RecyclerView was not called upon returning from the new activity. As I learned, this is to be expected, because startActivityForResult was not called from this fragment.

The closest thing to a solution I found was this:
[onActivityResult inside a RecyclerView.Adapter not being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243560/onactivityresult-inside-a-recyclerview-adapter-not-being-used/35243593)

But when trying to use an interface to implement the onClick method, I now face a new problem: I can't call the onClick method inside the adapter, although it's implemented inside the activity, because the Adapter's context is static, and the method is non-static.

Below are some code portions to explain better the current situations. I'm in desperate need for an alternative solution, I really searched through and through. Thanks.

The fragment implements the interface:

```
public class EditableOffersListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickButtonListener { ...

    @Override
    public void onClickButton(View v, int position, ArrayList<Offer> offers) {
        Offer from_item = offers.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OfferDetailsPopupActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("new", false);
        intent.putExtra("offer_fromRecycler", from_item);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, HTZ_ADD_OFFER);
    }
...}
```

The interface (in a seperate file):

```
public interface OnClickButtonListener {
    void onClickButton(View v, int position, ArrayList<Offer> offers);
}
```

And inside the adapter:

```
            mEditOfferButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    OnClickButtonListener.onClickButton(v, getAdapterPosition(), mOffers);
                }
            });
```

Comment: If you call `startActivityForResult` from the `getActivity()` method then the callback `onActivityResult` will be handled by the Activity holding the fragment. If you instead do `this.startActivityForResult` (being `this` the reference to the fragment) then the callback will be handled by the fragment that actually launched the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally solved it.

What worked was adding a OnClickButtonListener member to the Adapter, which is passed from the Fragment in the Adapter's constructor (the Fragment is implementing OnClickButtonListener so I just passed 'this' to the constructor).

That way, all of the actions performed in the adapter are on an instance of OnClickButtonListener and the static/non-static problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're currently facing is that you're calling `startActivityForResult` from the `Activity` containing the current fragment rather than the Fragment itself. So using `this` or just plainly calling the `startActivityForResult` will call it from the Fragment instead of the `Activity` and this `fragment` will be callbacked with the result from the other `Activity`.

```
public class EditableOffersListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickButtonListener { ...

    @Override
    public void onClickButton(View v, int position, ArrayList<Offer> offers) {
            Offer from_item = offers.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OfferDetailsPopupActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("new", false);
            intent.putExtra("offer_fromRecycler", from_item);
            startActivityForResult(intent, HTZ_ADD_OFFER); // <--- Note that this line has changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Do your result handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you might be right, but still I face the issue that in the Adapter (last piece of code), I get the error 'non static method cannot be called from a static context'...

Comment: I can't really see any `static` variables on the code you've provided so I can't really tell what is and what is not `static`.

Let me know if I can give you further help

Comment: The static context is the Adapter, as far as I understand. There are no explicitly declared static variables, just a static context..